# Using AppDomain to load DLL as embedded resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain

How can I load more than 1 file DLL using

```
(( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler() ))
```

It's just the first one working but the other one not working ?!!
I need to load both DLL file embedded resources, so I can use the application without the files !!

```
     public MainWindow()
    {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve2);
        InitializeComponent();
    }


 static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DS.WpfAnimatedGif.dll"))
        {
            byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }

    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve2(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DS.Newtonsoft.Json.dll"))
        {
            byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you return from the first event handler, the next one is ignored.

This is [as per the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> If more than one event handler is registered for this event, the event handlers are called in order until an event handler returns a value that isn't null. Subsequent event handlers are ignored.

Comment: didnt got it , i need to load 2 dll files in my programe , how can i do it ?!